# how to remove the array to string conversion error in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, phpmyadmin

i am working on php i have dynamic array i need to get the array result store in some variable i encounter the error :`array to string conversion`
coding

```
   <?php
require_once('ag.php');
class H
 {
    var $Voltage;
    var $Number;
    var $Duration;
function H($Voltage=0,$Number=0,$Duration=0)
     {
        $this->Voltage = $Voltage;
        $this->Number = $Number;
        $this->Duration = $Duration;
    }}
//This will be the crossover function. Is just the average of all properties.
function avg($a,$b) {
return round(($a*2+$b*2)/2);
}
//This will be the mutation function. Just increments the property.
function inc($x)
 {
    return $x+1*2;
}
//This will be the fitness function. Is just the sum of all properties.

function debug($x) 
{
    echo "<pre style='border: 1px solid black'>";
    print_r($x);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
//This will be the fitness function. Is just the sum of all properties.
function total($obj) 
{
return $obj->Voltage*(-2) + $obj->Number*2 + $obj->Duration*1;
}
$asma=array();
for($i=0;$i<$row_count;$i++) 
{
$adam = new H($fa1[$i],$fb1[$i],$fcc1[$i]);
$eve = new H($fe1[$i],$ff1[$i],$fg1[$i]);
$eve1 = new H($fi1[$i],$fj1[$i],$fk1[$i]);
$ga = new GA();
echo "Input"; 
$ga->population = array($adam,$eve,$eve1);
debug($ga->population);
$ga->fitness_function = 'total';    //Uses the 'total' function as fitness function
$ga->num_couples = 5;               //4 couples per generation (when possible)
$ga->death_rate = 0;                //No kills per generation
$ga->generations = 10;              //Executes 100 generations
$ga->crossover_functions = 'avg';   //Uses the 'avg' function as crossover function
$ga->mutation_function = 'inc';     //Uses the 'inc' function as mutation function
$ga->mutation_rate = 20;            //10% mutation rate
$ga->evolve();                      //Run
echo "BEST SELECTED POPULATION";
debug(GA::select($ga->population,'total',3)); //The best
 $array=array((GA::select($ga->population,'total',3))); //The best }

?>
  <?php

$comma_separated = implode(",", $array); 
echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
?
```

>
i apply implode function but its not working
it display the error of `: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\EMS3\ge.php on line 146` at line `$r=implode($rt,",");`

Comment: you again? same question?

Comment: becoz i am not getting the solution

Comment: You want to use the value of textboxB in your php code (if else condition) right ??????

Comment: yes sir @moeed farooqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
if (   ($textboxB.val)==31.41)
{
</script>

<?php echo "as,dll;g;h;'islamabad"; ?>

<script>} </script>
```

You are running your java script code in PHP, I havent implemented your code just checked and found this bug.You can get the value by submitting the form also

---------------------------- Answer For your Second updated  question------------------------

```
<?php
$array = array(
      "name" => "John",
      "surname" => "Doe",
      "email" => "j.doe@intelligence.gov"
   );
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array); // You can implode them with any character like i did with ,

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
?>
```

Comment: sir i have another issuse if u can resolve it i shall be thankful to you its related to array to string conversion error

Comment: Please paste your code in question and error also in order to get the idea

Comment: @aniya kindly create another question,its a bad practice.provide link here

Comment: i am sory for this can u provide me the answer if i have any other query i will proceed fuurther

Comment: it still display the same srror